rename to escaped reserved column name
there is a reserved column transaction in my table maria db and my goal change the column to the same name but with an escaped symbol I try did it like that but still faced with a column name without an escaped backtick
ALTER TABLE test_tbl
    CHANGE COLUMN transaction `transaction` varchar (200) NOT NULL;

and then when looking on the table through PHP storm faced with the same name, but the I have also unique column which looks ok
-- auto-generated definition
create table test_tbl
(
    id               int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
 
    transaction      varchar(200)         not null,
    `unique`         char(32)             not null,


backticks are NOT escaping. If you cannot change the name to something not in the reserved list [the best solution] then you have to use the backticks around the reserved word to allow it to be used in normal coding

But actually transactions is not a reserved word it is a keyword FOR REFERENCE

reserved words are listed in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/; transaction is not a reserved word.  can you tell us what led you to want to change it?

even if it were a reserved word, an alter table like that doesn't fix it.  you need to use backticks in every sql request that uses a reserved word as an identifier.

So the problem is PHP storm isn't auto-generating a backticked quoted transaction? Is this based on the table in the database? If you want to apply it, add backticks to the auto-generated defination.

Any general utility (eg storm?) should backtic every column name, etc.  This would future-proof it.  Complain to them.
